# Merging CSV in AWS S3 into larger GZIP files via Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm looking to run a large job with AWS Athena. I have about 650 100mb - 1.5GB CSV files. My goal is to merges these into fewer Gzipped CSV files into another file.

I created a table over this data using AWS Athena. Is it possible to run a job like this? The existing format is just standard CSV (3 columns)

## Table Attempt

```
CREATE TABLE NODES_GZIPPED_NODESTEST2
WITH (
      external_location = 's3://mybucket',
      format = 'TEXTFILE',
      bucketed_by=ARRAY['accessedtime'],
      bucket_count = 20
 )

AS SELECT *
FROM NodeRun2CSV3
LIMIT 50000
```

In this case, the commas are missing in the output files. How can I ensure instead of:

data1data2 I would get data1,data2?

Comment: You question is not clear. Do all these files have same structure? Are they totally unrelated? What have you tried yourself so far? Join how? Row or column wise?

Comment: Hi Marcin. The CSVs are all of the same format. There are many of them and I'm looking to merge them. For example, if I have 600 files, I want only 30 output files. I'm able to output GZIP files, but the only thing missing at this point is the comma. Is it possible to specify that? I'll post the query

Comment: How do you intend to use the resulting files? Will they be used by Athena, or by some other process (and is that other process expecting a particular format)?

Comment: I'm trying to get these prepared for a Neptune bulk load. The current neptune load seems to be slow. I was hoping that having large CSV files would help the parallelization, although I can't find anything in the docs confirming that to be true. Neptune takes in CSV or gzip. I got this from the docs saying large CSV files can be broken up for more performant concurrency.

Comment: Try defining the table as CSV using [OpenCSVSerDe for Processing CSV - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html).